# How can I configure SVN to deploy when I commit?

Tags: svn, deployment

How can I configure SVN to deploy when I commit? I would like to deploy when I commit

Comment: Where do you want to deploy? On the repository (SVN) server, on a build server, on another workstation?

Comment: on the same server, I would like to put all files in a directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to modify the post commit hook. Placed here:

```
PATH_TO_YOUR_REPO/hooks/post-commit.tmpl
```

Change it's name (or create a new one and save that one for future reference) to:

```
PATH_TO_YOUR_REPO/hooks/post-commit
```

Then `chown` it and `chmod` it let your svn user (tipically `apache`) execute that file:

```
chown apache.apache PATH_TO_YOUR_REPO/hooks/post-commit
chmod g+x PATH_TO_YOUR_REPO/hooks/post-commit
```

Assuming you want to export your repo's trunk to a local path, here is what I use to automatically deploy to my testing server, which is also my SVN repo server (I do not recommend using this to deploy to production servers, use a custom script for that). This will look for a `**DEPLOY**` tag in your commit message and deploy only if that's the case.

```
#!/bin/sh
REPO="$1"
REV="$2"

if ( svnlook log -r $REV $REPO | grep "**DEPLOY**" ) then
    svn export --force -r $REV "file://$REPO/trunk" /var/www/html/yourapp
fi
```

Comment: I think that you should mention that the instruction applies only to linux machines.

Comment: Good point. It works also on Mac OS and in every system that suports SVN & Shell. Are there others? :P

Comment: Does this export the entire project every time?

Comment: @johnny Yes it does.

Answer (score 1):

look at hook scripts section at [Repository Creation and Configuration](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch05s02.html) you can write a shell script to do pretty much anything/anywhere...

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but not recommended to use post commit hook. It will make developer to wait for the commit to complete until the hook execution has finished.

For professional solution Continuous Integration tool should be used, like: CruiseControl, Jenkins or one of many other.